# Class isn't conforming to NSCoding protocol

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, nscoding

I've been using apple's guide for saving data in swift, but when I try to compile it's telling me that is isn't conforming. Based on apple's guide and other code it should be.

```
// MARK: NSCoding

func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encodeObject(firstName, forKey: "firstName")
    aCoder.encodeObject(lastName, forKey: "lastName")
    aCoder.encodeObject(phoneNumber, forKey: "phoneNumber")
    aCoder.encodeObject(email, forKey: "email")
    aCoder.encodeObject(address, forKey: "address")
}

required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    firstName = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("firstName") as! String
    lastName = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("lastName") as! String
    phoneNumber = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("phoneNumber") as! String
    email = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("email") as! String
    address = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("addressq") as! String

    self.init(phoneNumber: phoneNumber, firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName, email: email, address: address)
}
```

So I'm simply not sure why it isn't conforming when I can run Apple's program fine.

EDIT: So the problem seems to be that I didn't have my class inherited from NSObject. That solved the problem.

Comment: Can you show your `class` definition line?

Answer (score 0):

No errors here:

```
class Dog {
    var firstName: String

    func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encodeObject(firstName, forKey: "firstName")
    }

    init(firstName: String) {
        self.firstName = firstName
    }

    required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        let x = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("firstName") as! String

        self.init(firstName: x)
    }

}

var d = Dog(firstName: "Rover")
```

Comment: Your class doesn't state that it adopts the NSCoding protocol. It needs to do this and also inherit from NSObject to be a valid example